# Object-Oriented Sequential Fractal ArrayList query

Tags: processing

I am attempting to code a fractal in processing and have the generations/depth update sequentially with either the frameRate or mousePressed functionality. I understand that one way to achieve this is by treating the generations as objects and using two ArrayLists... one for the initial state and one to store the next generation.

Attached is my code in progress. Any help would be very much appreciated. I am  trying to precalculate the curves and operations via the constructor of the class and add them to a new Arraylist, (which would then become the current one). I wish to accomplish this without erasing the previous generation.

EDIT/////////////////////////////////////////
Here I have nearly worked out a solution, but it is not quite there yet as the pervious generation of the fractal is erased when the current arrayList becomes the next generation.

```
ArrayList<Fractal> circle;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  //start with one circle
  circle = new ArrayList<Fractal>();
  //pass in the initial constructor
  circle.add(new Fractal(width/2, height/2, 200));
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  //show all circles??? with an enhanced forLoop
  for (Fractal f : circle) {
    f.display();
  }
}

//mousePressed advances the sequence
void mousePressed() {
  generate();
}

void generate() {
  //generate next set of circles
  ArrayList<Fractal> next = new ArrayList<Fractal>();
  for (Fractal f : circle) {
    next.add(new Fractal(f.x + f.r/2, f.y, f.r/2));
    next.add(new Fractal(f.x - f.r/2, f.y, f.r/2));
  }
  circle = next;
}


class Fractal {
  float x, y, r;

  public Fractal (float x, float y, float r  ) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(x, y, r, r);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

You've got quite a few compilation errors and logic problems here. Let's start here:

```
  ////serious issues here###############################
  float moveA() {
    CircleFractal(x + r/2, y, r/2);
    drawCircle(x - r/2, y, r/2, num);
    drawCircle(x, y + r/2, r/2, num);
    drawCircle(x, y - r/2, r/2, num);
    return moveA.get();
  }
```

You aren't lying about there being serious issues here. (In the future, please try to be more specific: what issues? What exactly are you trying to do here?)

But from the way you're trying to use this function, I'm going to guess that you basically want it to return the next generation for a particular circle. That means you're going to have to return an `ArrayList`. Also, you don't want to draw them yet, just return them. So it might look something like this:

```
ArrayList<CircleFractal> moveA() {
    ArrayList<CircleFractal> myChildren = new ArrayList<CircleFractal>();
    myChildren.add(new CircleFractal(x + r/2, y, r/2));
    myChildren.add(new CircleFractal(x - r/2, y, r/2));
    myChildren.add(new CircleFractal(x, y + r/2, r/2));
    myChildren.add(new CircleFractal(x, y - r/2, r/2));
    return myChildren;
}
```

Then in your `generate()` function, you can just call it like this:

```
next.addAll(c.moveA());
```

But note that your logic for keeping track of the already drawn `CircleFractals` doesn't make a ton of sense. You're only ever storing the latest generation in the `circles` variable, so if you want to go back and change the color of the first generation, you aren't going to be able to do that.

Instead, you might create an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`, that way you have access to the circles of each generation. Or you could store all of them in the same `ArrayList`, but then you have to be careful about which ones you're creating children for.

Anyway, back to your compilation errors: the `nextLevel()` function doesn't seem to actually do anything, so I'd just remove it.

And why is your `restart()` function inside the `CircleFractal` class? Does it ever make sense to restart a single circle? And why do you call the `restart()` function from the `CircleFractal` constructor? You're restarting your simulation every time you add a circle? That's probably not right. So I'd move the `restart()` function out of that class, and stop calling the `restart()` function from the `CircleFractal` constructor. You also need to add the first generation (the single circle in the middle) to the `ArrayList` when you restart the animation.

You've also got a `count` variable in your `CircleArray` class that doesn't seem to make a ton of sense. You seem to be trying to track the generation number, which means you need to increment that variable when you create a new generation. So I'd make `generationCount` a sketch-level variable, then increment it in the `generate()` function.

Then you've got a `CircleFractal c;` variable at the top that you aren't using, so I'd get rid of that.

From there then you just need to uncomment the `display()` function and then call that. Keep in mind the above issue where you're only ever tracking the latest generation.

### Start smaller!

Honestly, if I were you, I would just start with a simpler sketch. Don't worry about the fractal or the animation yet. Get a single circle displaying. Then get the children of that first circle working: don't worry about any subsequent generations yet, just get 5 circles working. Can you add them to data structures that allow you to change their colors? Only after you get that working perfectly, then you can start thinking about the third generation.

Start smaller and work in smaller steps, that way you don't find yourself in a mess with a bunch of code that doesn't really work. Then if you get stuck on a specific step you can post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question, as it's pretty hard to help general "I don't know how to do this" type questions. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I agree with all of your points. Ironically, this is the simpler version of what I wanted to compose initially. Nevertheless, I appreciate your analysis of my logical errors. Also, I should have been more specific with the 'serious issues' section - there I unsure how to phrase it, but I wanted to somehow make sense of where I should create the action of the fractal (either in the sketch or the object tab). I have attempted in starting small and created the sketch you suggested, I will see if I can move forward slowly and implement your suggestions! I appreciate your insight!

Comment: Hello Kevin, I have attempted to simplify the code and have it working; except for the fact that my previous iteration is erased when I pass the next generation into the new ArrayList. I am sure I am overlooking something rather simple. Thank you again for all of your help.

Comment: @ErikSvenBroberg I'll be happy to help, but do you mind posting your updated code in a new question? It's hard to follow threads if there are a bunch of edits in the questions and answers. Stack Overflow is more designed for "one question one answer" type posts.